# How to redirect after validate method fails in Laravel

Tags: php, validation, laravel-6

I am using Laravel 6, and I created a form to insert new users into my database. I want to change the route of the redirect method if the validator fails. I tried many times to do that but always when the validator fails I see the errors in the current view (adminArea.blade.php) and not in the home view (home.blade.php).

```php
public function insert_user(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'name' => 'required',
        'surname' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
        'pwd' => 'required',
        'permission' => 'required',
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return redirect()->route('home')->withErrors($validator);
    }

    $user = new User();
    $user->name = request('name');
    $user->surname = request('surname');
    $user->email = request('email');
    $user->password = Hash::make(request('pwd'));
    $user->permission = request('permission');
    $user->save();

    $message_correct = request('name')." ".request('surname')." has been correctly inserted!";

    return redirect()->route('home')->with('success', $message_correct);
}
```

Currently, the submission of the form is OK and it redirects correctly to the home view. However, if the submission fails it remains on the same page (adminArea.blade.php). Is there a way to redirect the errors in the home view if the submission fails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I can see in your validation, you are using the `Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests@validate` method to validate your data, in this way you should use `try catch`  block to catch `ValidationException` thrown when the validation is failed.

I suggest you use `Validator`, so your method will be like below:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator

public function insert_user(Request $request)
    {
        $validator = Validator::make($request, [
            'name' => 'required',
            'surname' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
            'pwd' => 'required',
            'permission' => 'required',
        ]);

        if($validator->fails()) {
            return redirect()->route('home')->withErrors($validator);
        }
        $user = new User();
        $user->name = request('name');
        $user->surname = request('surname');
        $user->email = request('email');
        $user->password = Hash::make(request('pwd'));
        $user->permission = request('permission');
        $user->save();
        $message_correct = request('name') . " " . request('surname') . " has been correctly inserted!";   
        return redirect()->route('home')->with('success', $message_correct); 
    }
```